# nginx get root based on url regex with some calculation rules

Tags: nginx

Given url like this: media/images/293_84072edb91d2b62387f529e2c4456c85f4dadee5

I wanna get path with following rules:

if

```
 location ~* /media/images/\d*_(?<hash>[a-z0-9]{40})
```

then

take var $hash (84072edb91d2b62387f529e2c4456c85f4dadee5), get first char of it ('8'), for example let's name it with $hash[0]
then second and third chars together ('40'), named by $hash[1:3]
and then root where nginx can take the image must look like this one:

media/images/$hash[1]/$hash[1:3]/$hash
root -> media/images/8/40/84072edb91d2b62387f529e2c4456c85f4dadee5

How can I write this rule? Please, help me to understand.

Comment: So `293_` prefix is ignored?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, yes, it should be ignored

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
location ~ ^/media/images/\d*_(?<hash0>[a-z0-9])(?<hash13>[a-z0-9]{2})(?<hash>[a-z0-9]{37})$ {
  alias /server/path/$hash0/$hash13/$hash0$hash13$hash;
}
```

BTW, in pure nginx you can't work with string as in programming language. Nginx has only regexp.

But regexp can get any part of string as group. In your example 40 symbols of hash captured as named group. But you can easy create 2 capture groups: one with 1 symbol, second - with next 39 symbols. Or, can create 3 capture groups: with 1 symbol (`(?<hash0>[a-z0-9])` in mine example), with next 2 symbols (`(?<hash13>[a-z0-9]{2})`) and with next 37 symbols (`(?<hash>[a-z0-9]{37})`). All groups has own name. Now we can create path using this captures.

Btw, name of groups are not required, this example can be written as

```
location ~ ^/media/images/\d*_([a-z0-9])([a-z0-9]{2})([a-z0-9]{37})$ {
  alias /server/path/$1/$2/$1$2$3;
}
```

Named group important if you have few different regexp (in location, in server name, in if etc).

Now, why `alias` and not `root`. Root - it's sever root for this location. If location /a/ and `root /home/www/` - filepath of /a/test.txt will be /home/www/a/test.txt. Alias replace current location, so if `alias /home/www/` - filepath of /a/test.txt will be /home/www/test.txt.

So use root if your location and file structure the same, and alias - if location do not map to file system path directly.

Comment: I would add `^` to beginning of regexp. `location ~ ^/media/...`

Comment: Yep, true, missed it. And probably default_type inside location =)

Comment: Yes, it's working, but could you add example for more general case, how to slice variable into parts? Thank you.

Comment: Edited. Tell me if you still have any questions.

Comment: @Terra, tnank you for the explanation